# How can I check that a mongo update command succeeded in node

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to check that an update command accomplished but when I check for the `nModified` I'm getting 0 although I do see that the field value changes from one value to another (not kept the same value).

```
static async updateProfile(username, profileData)  {
  const usersCollection = db.dbConnection.collection(dbConfig.collectionNames.users);
  const updateRes = await usersCollection.update({email: username}, 
    {"$set": {
      firstName: profileData.firstName,
      lastName: profileData.lastName,
      payment: profileData.payment,
    }
  });
  return updateRes.result.nModified > 0;
}
```

Is there another way to verify the update?

Comment: Is there nMatched?

Comment: Yep, 1 nMatched in the result

Comment: Do you have `n` in your `updateRes`? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#output

Answer (score 0):

One of the way by [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) method:
You can easily compare whole new object and verify each key.

```
db.getCollection('usertests').findAndModify({
    query: {"email":"xxx@xxx.com"},
    update: {name: "HHH", "email":"xxx@xxx.com"},
    new: true
})
```

> **new: true** is responsible to return whole updated document. If fail to update it will return `null`.
>
> Take care here to pass the whole document while update.

`update()` only return a number of the documents that were successfully updated. So, your logic to check if updated successfully or not is also valid.