# Nodejs, Mongodb follow/unfollow request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am making an social web app where user can follow each other and have followers and following option. I coded all the logic for follow but the problem is one user can follow same user again and again as many time user want but I want one user can follow other only one time not more than that How It can be done? Here below is my code.

**userschema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    avatar:{
        type:String,
    },
    following: [
        { 
            type: Schema.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'User' 
        },

    ],
    followers: [
        { 
            type: Schema.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'User' 
        }
    ],
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**user router**

```
router.post("/user/:user_id/follow-user",  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session:false}), (req,res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id)
        .then(user => {
            user.followers.push(req.user._id);
            var followedUser = user._id;
            user.save()
            User.findOne({ email: req.user.email })
                .then(user => {
                    user.following.push(followedUser);
                    user.save().then(user => res.json(user))
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I had solved it by own after trying so many methods and I had also change my UserSchema for solving this below is my code. I also added a method so user cannot follow himself/herself.

**UserSchema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    avatar:{
        type:String,
    },
    following: [
        {
            user:{ 
                type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'User' 
            },
        }

    ],
    followers: [
        {
            user:{ 
                type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                ref: 'User' 
            },
        }
    ],
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**user.js**

```
router.post("/user/:user_id/follow-user",  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session:false}), (req,res) => {

    // check if the requested user and :user_id is same if same then 

    if (req.user.id === req.params.user_id) {
        return res.status(400).json({ alreadyfollow : "You cannot follow yourself"})
    } 

    User.findById(req.params.user_id)
        .then(user => {

            // check if the requested user is already in follower list of other user then 

            if(user.followers.filter(follower => 
                follower.user.toString() === req.user.id ).length > 0){
                return res.status(400).json({ alreadyfollow : "You already followed the user"})
            }

            user.followers.unshift({user:req.user.id});
            user.save()
            User.findOne({ email: req.user.email })
                .then(user => {
                    user.following.unshift({user:req.params.user_id});
                    user.save().then(user => res.json(user))
                })
                .catch(err => res.status(404).json({alradyfollow:"you already followed the user"}))
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/). This will not modify document if `id` is already exists.

```
var followedUser = user._id;
User.update(
    { email: req.user.email },
    { $addToSet: { following: followedUser, followers: req.user._id } }
).then(user => {
  // return response from here.
});
```

And, if you want to modified document back after modify, use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { name: "hardik" },
  { $addToSet: { following: followedUser,followers: req.user._id } }, 
  {new: true})
.then(user => {
  // retunr whole modified document.
});
```

You can check one of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009992/9369945).

Comment: no it's not working for me. on first attempt it is adding followers and following correctly but still showing error and if i try to follow same user again still it is added to followers but this time it is not adding to following

Comment: Yes that is what, I have written query. I have taken care about following array only. You can use addtoset for followers array too.

Comment: @chiragprajapati Check edited answer for both case `followers` and `following`